# Make Javascript code wait for user to click "OK" on jAlert box to submit

Tags: javascript, submit, alert

Given a specific condition I would like for an alert to pop up and a message be conveyed to the user before they proceed. However I am not sure how to do this. Right now, the alert simply pops up and you barely have time to read the text before the page refreshes. Any suggestions?

```
if ((address != 'undefined' && googleValue != "ROOFTOP") &&
       !(address == "" && googleValue == "APPROXIMATE")) {
    jAlert("Exact request could not be processed, results have been returned at an approximate level.");
}

$("#Latitude").val(latlng.lat());
$("#Longitude").val(latlng.lng());
$("#formSearch").submit();
```

Comment: That's not possible out of the box with jAlert.

Comment: [link](http://www.smooka.com/blog/2009/02/22/jalert-jquery-alert-box-plugin/) The comments from the developer on this page confirm this as well.

Comment: Can you use jAlert to get a return of any sort?

Answer (score 1):

This question was asked quite a while back, 
For completeness, this functionality now exists with jAlert.

You can register a callback with the jAlert call, to allow the code to be executed on completion, once the ok button has been clicked.

```
if ((address != 'undefined' && googleValue != "ROOFTOP") &&
             !(address == "" && googleValue == "APPROXIMATE")) {
        jAlert("Exact request ...", function(answer) { 
                $("#Latitude").val(latlng.lat());
                $("#Longitude").val(latlng.lng());
                $("#formSearch").submit();
            });
        }
```

Comment: Callback function on Ok click is not called. What is wrong?

  $.jAlert({
                'title': title,
                'content': error,
                'theme': "red",
                'backgroundColor': 'white',
                'btns': [
                    { 'text': 'OK', 'theme': 'red' }
                ], function(answer) {
                    alert('Hello');
                    if (document.getElementById(inputitem).type != 'hidden') {
                        document.getElementById(inputitem).focus();
                    }
                }
     -       });